# Selecting columns after 3 days have passed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a user generated date from the html5 form element "date"(or 2013-01-06 if their browser doesn't support html5). I'm looking to select and output dates only after 3 days have passed.

I've looked around stack overflow and found a few threads that looked promising and came up with(table = files1, date column = datec):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files1 WHERE DATEDIFF(day, now(), datec) >3";

$result = mysql_query($query,$con);

echo $result;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

foreach($row as $name => $value){
    echo "$name: $value\t";

}//end foreach


}//end while
```

However this produces:
     "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" which I've found to come from the query not executing.

Comment: What does `mysql_error` tell you? (See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a create/date column in your table you could select by that using date_add

Try DATE_ADD

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

but to use datediff:

```
DATEDIFF(now(),$seconddategoeshere)
```